# Contact Form 7 add action to Submit

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Im trying to add action to the FC1 submit button, but i cant really find anywhere on the net the right function for it.
The only one i found called `"wpcf7_before_send_mail"`
can i cant really get it to work

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'mytheme_save_to_getresponse', 10, 1);
function mytheme_save_to_getresponse($form)
{
   echo "testing";
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: i noticed that the echo is not working because there is no actual page to echo and its causing it an error, so how do i know the function is added?

Comment: If you want to test that it is running, you can write to the PHP error log with `error_log("testing");`

Comment: And if you want to write the contents of an object: `ob_start();
var_dump($form);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
error_log($contents);`

Comment: you can post it as answer, thank you.